# what is the Exclamation mark mean in eclipse ? android project

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I just do some update to the ADT plugin, and then an Exclamation mark appear next to my project.
I check the build path and found a problem with android dependencies:
[image]

what should I do ?

this another picture :
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exclamation icon means that your project has one or more broken entries on its classpath. On the posted screen capture, you can see which entry has a problem. Follow the listed path and you will see that it is missing.

From your screen capture, it looks like the same library is present in another classpath entry  (Android Private Libraries). Since you don't need the same library twice, you may be able to just remove "Android Dependencies" entry.

Comment: yes that is right, there is another path to the same library, actually I don't know how this happened" I don't do any thing except updating the ADT ", what is android dependencies file is ?

Answer (score 0):

The symbol you're referring to is a warning.  It's not a gamebreaker, like an actual compilation error (red symbol with an X).  It's just a means of letting you know something is not exactly correct.  Like, missing a description in a XML tag, or something.

I posted this before the graphic loaded.  So I didn't see that you are finding something altogether more complicated.  For this, I would recommend looking at the code itself and finding the offending line.  It should be highlighted.

Comment: actually when i just try to run the android project , this message appear : "your project contains error"

Comment: Right.  That's a compilation error.  There is a file there in your screen grab that has an error in it.  You'll have to open that file and see what the error message is.  If you can't figure it out, post that.  We'll likely have a better shot at helping.

Comment: YES , this a android-supprot-v7 library , it is from google ! I don't think should be there any error !

Comment: Be that as it may, there appears to be one.  It may have something to do with your installation.  What does the error message say?

Comment: This answer is wrong. The exclamation icon is not a warning!

Comment: I thought he was talking about the little yellow triangle with an exclamation point.  That IS a warning.  You can even supress them if you'd like.